# Retrieve users into particular group using Javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, groups, user

I have created 2 groups(`epm` and `mobile`). I inserted some users into particular group.

How can I retrieve users based on current group?

For example in a dropdown if I choose `emp` group I want to show `epm` users only.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set the SharePoint group in the People Picker?

[image]

Comment: That would not be very dynamic though?

Comment: That's why I said Maybe.. with only a few groups you could add all People Pickers to a form and hide them based on a selection field... kludgy.. but Maybe it helps.

Comment: Possibly. I see an issue with doing this on the field level in that scenario though, you would need one people column per possible group, kludgy to say the least ;)

Comment: Hey... if you never try the difficult routes you will never know if the current route is the easy one... [Me] thinks Display Template is the way to go: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 But it requires some more coding to get the Group selector.

Comment: Yupp, JSLink is a valid path I think ( might also be the reason whe OP states he wants to do it with javascript)

Comment: One Group selector and TWO People Pickers on a New/EditForm and 4 lines of (SP native) $mQuery JavaScript in a CEWP can do the job... but indeed.. kludgy